# How to insert object to MySQL using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

I write code to read RFID tag using Python, check the existence of the ID in the database.

If successful, right ID on database led is ON, but command insert to database not work. Python gives no error message, and I do not understand what's wrong with it.

How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
import serial
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import MySQLdb
from datetime import datetime
from binascii import hexlify
serial=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",                    
                      baudrate=9600,                     
                      parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,                    
                      stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,                    
                      bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                      timeout=0.1) 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) 
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
chuoi= "\xAA\x00\x03\x25\x26\x00\x00\xBB"
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='root', db='ex_1')
cur = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
while 1:   
    serial.write(chuoi)      
    data =serial.readline()    
    tach = data[5:8]    
    hex = hexlify(tach)   
    num = int(hex,16)    
    print(num)      
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM thong_tin WHERE Card_ID = '%d'" %num)    
    rows = cur.fetchall()    
    for row in rows:    
            ID = row['Card_ID']     
            if( num == ID):     
                     GPIO.output(12, True)
                    cur.execute("INSERT INTO data (Card_ID,Time_out,Time_in) VALUES ('%d',NOW(),NOW())" %num) #-> it does not add to database   
                    time.sleep(3)       
                    GPIO.output(12, False);     
            else:       
                    GPIO.output(12, False);
```

Comment: And what exactly is the error that you are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have a indentation error in your code:

```
        if( num == ID):     
                 GPIO.output(12, True)
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO data (Card_ID,Time_out,Time_in) VALUES ('%d',NOW(),NOW())" %num) #-> it does not add to database   
                time.sleep(3)       
                GPIO.output(12, False);
```

One line is indented more than the others.

Also you do not have to use ; at the end of the line in Python. And you should not use the normal string formating with DB queries for security reason (SQL injections). From the MySQLdb User's Guide:

```
c.execute("""SELECT spam, eggs, sausage FROM breakfast
      WHERE price < %s""", (max_price,))
```

This form will automatically quote the values in a safe way.

Comment: Can you update the code above? Maybe there are more problems.

Comment: I will check it carefully, then can you help me?